# How do I combine arbitrarily-ranked lists?

Tags: classification

Look, I know the basic answer is either “you don’t” or “you need much more information”. I strongly suspect that there isn’t a fully rigorous way to do this. That said, I am still hopeful there is a reasonably good way, because my specific use case doesn’t need full rigor. On to the actual question:

I have about a thousand items, some of which are “bad”. There are three orthogonal measures of badness, and I can get a ranked list of items by each measure of badness. I need a filter that ranks the overall baddest items, based on the three individual rankings. I can access the metric values, but they are orthogonal to each other and not readily normalizable.

The good news is that a combined list would be interpreted by humans. It does **not** need perfect rigor. It does need to provide reasonable confidence to its users, so frequent “surprising” results are bad.

---

Strict ordering is not critical, though the order should not be chaotic.
*It's fine if small changes swap #3 and #4; it is not fine if small changes swap #3 and #600.*

An item that is high badness in one list should be high overall.

For example, if the starting lists are:

```
   1. Ape            1. Fish           1. Fish
   2. Bat            2. Heron          2. Heron
   3. Cat            3. Cat            3. Cat
   4. Gorilla        4. Lynx           4. Mouse   
     ...              ...               ...
 500. Fish         500. Ape          500. Ape
```

Then the ending list should probably have Fish as #1, Ape, Heron, and Cat next (no opinion on which order is correct), then Bat. Any algorithm which generates a similar answer is good.

---

Finally, if there truly is no generalizable solution, that's also useful to know. I remain hopeful that isn't the case.

Comment: What do you mean by "orthogonal"? What exactly do you mean by "not readily normalizable"? What's wrong with just averaging the three values (if for some reason this doesn't work with the metric values, you could average the ranks)?

Comment: The values are, roughly, a count of one kind of event, a duration, and a unitless numerical measure. the unitless measure could normalize to a scale from 1-10 (or whatever), but the difference between "2" and "3" would not be the same a "6" and "7". Averaging the ranks might work, but is probably not ideal: if the ranks for a left-handed corkscrew are 1,601,601; the average is 401, when it should come out somewhere near the top.

Comment: your comment that "*if the ranks for a left-handed corkscrew are 1,601,601; the average is 401, when it should come out somewhere near the top*" implies you know/understand some things that are *not at all obvious* from your post. *We* cannot supply - or likely even correctly guess at - this knowledge.

Comment: I imagine you can at least explain some sense of what you'd seek instead in more depth.

Comment: To elaborate on what @Glen_b has written, it will probably work to have some kind of function of the ranks that does what you want to do. This will need to be designed in such a way that it achieves what you want, for which reason we need to understand what you want (it may well be that it is enough if you yourself understand it properly, as this is at least half the work done). Just computing the average was my fist guess, but you could of course also take the best rank, or compute a weighted average with the best rank having double weight.

Comment: @Glen_b That's a fair point, and it may be that this is too poorly formed to be answerable. Let me take another crack at describing what success would look like.

Comment: What do you mean by generalizable?

Comment: @fectin there's a whole family of power means $\overline{{x}^p}^{1/p}$, which include as special or limiting cases harmonic means and geometric means. For example, the harmonic mean of (1,601,601) is about 3 while the geometric mean is about 70. At the same time the harmonic mean of (1,1,601) is about 1.5 and the geometric mean is about 8.4. Beyond power means there's other generalized means, $t^{-1}\left(\,\overline{t(x)}\,\right)$, for some strictly monotonic $t$. Perhaps there's a power mean or some other generalized mean that suits you?

Comment: Specifically perhaps a power mean with $p<-2$ (say) might be close to what you seek? $p$ at $-2$ would place Bat a bit better than Cat, but $-3$ places it lower. Alternatively, something based on the highest rank (i.e. the minimum of the ranks), with ties broken by the next best rank for each item.

Answer (score 2):

From your example it seems that you want to weight the top ranks heavily. 500-1-1 is ranked higher in your view than 3-3-3, and even 1-500-500 should still be rated high.

What about this: Rank accoording to top rank (i.e., anything that has a rank 1 comes first, then anything that has rank 2 but not 1 and so on. Among those having a rank 1, two rank 1 are better than one, and if there are still ties not resolved in this way, sort according to the next best rank. This will give Fish-Ape-Heron-Bat-Cat in your example. I do realise you want Cat above Bat, but it's really hard to arrange this if also you want Ape high up based on a single rank 1; unless you treat rank 1 essentially different from the later ranks.

Comment: This is a reasonable answer. I’m going to leave it unaccepted for a while in hopes that a better answer appears, but this may well be the best available. Thanks for playing along with my admittedly vague constraints.